# Akka: How to find the current nodes in a cluster?

Tags: java, scala, cluster-computing, akka, distributed-computing

From within an Akka actor, how can you find out the nodes of the cluster?
That is, the nodes which the local node considers to be currently accessible.

Thanks,
 - Daniel

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-usage.html#Subscribe_to_Cluster_Events

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You actually do not need to subscribe to `ClusterDomainEvent` or `MemberEvent`.  You can just access the `state` member of the Cluster extension, e.g.,

```
val cluster = akka.cluster.Cluster(context.system)

val members = cluster.state.members.filter(_.status == MemberStatus.Up)
```

Comment: In my experience (& I think this is mentioned in the docs somewhere) getting state this way is not guaranteed to be in sync. If you need a more accurate picture of state you need to do something like Patrik Nordwall suggests, parsing events in a cluster listener.

Comment: In my experience, you cannot mix the two idioms in the same actor.  Responding to Cluster events in receive is guaranteed to be behind the actual cluster state due to the latency of messages hanging around in mailboxes.

Comment: thx for clarification -- my use case though is that I need to perform split brain resolution when a member is removed, so how can the most up-to-date state be obtained in this situation if not self-managing? I don't think it's about mixing of idioms, more that getting state in this way can't be trusted. I think theres a ClusterState domain event that can be subscribed to that would be more accurate (since system is taking it upon itself to submit wholistic states via a listener) but probably lags on par with how long it takes this on-demand state method's response to change.

Answer (score 10):

Tweaked sample from [Typesafe Activator tutorial](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-clustering):

```
case object GetNodes

class MemberListener extends Actor {

  val cluster = Cluster(context.system)

  override def preStart(): Unit =
    cluster.subscribe(self, classOf[MemberEvent])

  override def postStop(): Unit =
    cluster unsubscribe self

  var nodes = Set.empty[Address]

  def receive = {
    case state: CurrentClusterState =>
      nodes = state.members.collect {
        case m if m.status == MemberStatus.Up => m.address
      }
    case MemberUp(member) =>
      nodes += member.address
    case MemberRemoved(member, _) =>
      nodes -= member.address
    case _: MemberEvent ⇒ // ignore
    case GetNodes =>
      sender ! nodes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach could be to have another actor subscribe into `ClusterDomainEvent` messages, specifically looking for the members via the `CurrentClusterState` event.  That might look something like this:

```
case object GetMembers

class ClusterMembersHolder extends Actor{
  var members:Set[Member] = Set()
  override def preStart = {
    val clusterSys = Cluster(context.system)
    clusterSys.subscribe(self, classOf[ClusterDomainEvent])
    clusterSys.publishCurrentClusterState //Forces the current state
  }

  def receive = {
    case state: CurrentClusterState =>
      members = state.members

    case GetMembers => 
      sender ! members
  }
}
```

This is kind of a rough outline (might need a few tweaks), but from here, any actor that wanted to know the current members list could send a GetMembers message to this actor via `?` and wait for the response.

Now this approach assumes that you might have many actors who want this info.  If it turns out that you only had one actor that wants this info then just have that actor subscribe into that event and update its internal state with the members.

Comment: The subscribing actor, `ClusterMemberHolder` must also handle `MemberUp` and `MemberRemoved` events. publishCurrentClusterState is not needed.