# Akka cluster: Get status information on nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, akka, akka-cluster

Given an Akka ActorSystem object, how can you find out what other nodes are active in the cluster, and what their status is?

Thank you,
 - Daniel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Akka: How to find the current nodes in a cluster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911862/akka-how-to-find-the-current-nodes-in-a-cluster)

Answer (score 5):

You should check out the docs under [Subscribe to Cluster Events](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/cluster-usage.html#Subscribe_to_Cluster_Events).  That should explain subscribing into cluster state changes at which point you will receive a `CurrentClusterState` event that shows the current state of the cluster.  From that point forward, you will start receiving incremental changes in the form of other events like `ClusterEvent.MemberUp` and `ClusterEvent.MemberRemoved` that help you continue to keep track of the state of the nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is directly to get `CurrentClusterState` by `Cluster`

```
val cluster = Cluster(ActorSystem("MyActorSystem"))
val status = cluster.state.members

val nodes = status.collect {
        case m if m.status == MemberStatus.Up => m.address
      }
```